# How to collect the IDs of same group from one file and write it in second file?

Tags: r

I have two big txt file.
The first file consists of two columns: **Group** and **ID**. Each group has different IDs. I want to collect all the IDs of every group in file A and add them to file B.
I tried to use `aggregate()` and `merge()`. But I was not sure that it was working correctly.
Can someone provide good solution to this?

The structure of my files and desired output are as follow:

```
File A
    Group       ID
    A/B/C       F1
    A/B/C       F5
    A/B/C       F7
    A/B/C       F6
    A/B/C       F8
    E/F         R1
    E/F         R2
    E/F         R4
    .
    .
    .
    .



File B
    Group           P  
    A/B/C           ls
    A/B/C           pr
    E/F             sh
    E/F             sh
    E/F             gn
    .
    .
    .


Desired output:

File B   
    Group     ID               P       
    A/B/C    F1/F5/F7/F6/F8    ls
    A/B/C    F1/F5/F7/F6/F8    pr
    E/F      R1/R2/R4          sh
    E/F      R1/R2/R4          sh
    E/F      R1/R2/R4          gn
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with `dplyr` library like this

```
df.A <- read.table(text="Group ID
A/B/C F1
A/B/C F5
A/B/C F7
A/B/C F6
A/B/C F8
E/F R1
E/F R2
E/F R4", header=T, sep=" ")

df.B <- read.table(text="Group P
A/B/C ls
A/B/C pr
E/F sh
E/F sh
E/F gn", header=T, sep=" ")

library(dplyr)

tmp <- df.A %.% group_by(Group) %.% summarise(ID=paste(ID, collapse="/"))
merge(tmp, df.B)
```